# How to provide the Notification in iphone.(GPS Notification)

Tags: iphone, mapkit, localnotification

I am building an application where i show the bus stops on the map and the user current location as well.I want to implement the notification that when the user is say x meters from one bus stop ,there should be a notification like alert,sound .So that he can prepare for his stop.There may be many stops on the map and i want to do it for everystop.
Please help me how to implement that.Whether it would be LocalNotification,Then how to use this in this way..........

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do all your distance calculations in `didUpdateToLocation`.

You can send local notifications in iOS 4, using UILocalNotification class.

Here is some sample code:

```
UILocalNotification *noti = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
noti.fireDate = someDate;
noti.alertBody = someText;
noti.alertAction = nil;
noti.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:noti];
[noti release];
```

Make sure the date is as close as possible as [NSDate date], so it will appear right away.

Comment: thanks for the reply,i have also seen that on apple doc,but i am not getting the way how to use in my app.Suppose i have 20 pins drops on the map.Then i need to loop to get the distance of all points one by one as the user location changes,then where would i put this notification,would that location would be in didUpdateToLocation,with in the loop or not.Please help me in that,and what about the firedate,should that be current date.

Comment: From what i understand I think its better if you check if the updated location is at the required distance from the point you want it to. I think you can pass the current location to the class where you plot the pins. I think you need to loop through them and then accordingly fire the notification.

Comment: Yes you are right,well i am trying this code in the simulator,i am just checking that how would it work,so i put the above code in the tableviews did select method,but i didn't see any Notification in the simulator ,whats wrong with that.I want to check this before i put this code in the main one.Can you help me in that